# What is the meaning of "dry of ~"?

Tags: usage

I have read this paragraph in the Economist.

> If retail banks were sucked **dry of funding**, someone else would have to do the lending that fuels business creation. This raises the queasy prospect of bureaucrats influencing credit allocation. In a crisis, a digital stampede of savers to the central bank could cause bank runs.

I was able to find out "suck something adjective."
[image]

But I am not sure what the meaning of "dry of something". Of course, I looked up the usage of dry as an adjective in the Oxford dictionary. [https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/dry_1?q=dry]

Only I could know is dry is used as an adjective, but there is no pattern of "dry of something".
Please help me out.

Comment: Do not post images of text without transcribing them.

Comment: "Dry of something" is not a phrase. The banks may be _sucked dry_, but not literally of liquid, like the greenfly and the plant, so it is necessary to add _of funding_ (meaning that the banks would lose all their money).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this:

> **milk/suck somebody/something dry**
>
> to get from someone or something all the money, help, information, etc. they have, usually giving nothing in return
>
> *By earning millions from racing and giving pennies back, the bookmakers are sucking the sport dry.*

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dry_1#dry_1__189

Answer (score 1):

It means, "without."  In the above example, "to suck a bank dry of funding," means to remove all of the bank's money.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a vessel of liquid, and you suck the liquid out through a pipe, there will come a moment when there is no liquid left. It is then said to be 'dry'. You have sucked it dry. To be more exact, dry **of** the liquid (gasoline, milk, beer, oil, whatever). Figuratively we can say that a supply of something has been exhausted by someone or something, using the same expression.